# Magento 2 Zoom in not working for mobile screens

Tags: magento2.2.6, zoom

we are using magneto 2.2.6, ethan theme for some website.Zoom option is working for desktop only for mobile screens it doesn't support here is our code

20 
 
             
             
            350 
            300 
            hover 
            true 
        
 
            
                
                    767px
                
                
                    
                        thumbs

```
    <var name="product_small_image_sidebar_size">100</var>  <!-- Override for small product image -->
    <var name="product_base_image_size">275</var>           <!-- Override for base product image -->
    <var name="product_base_image_icon_size">48</var>       <!-- Base product image icon size -->

    <var name="product_list_image_size">166</var>           <!-- New Product image size used in product list -->
    <var name="product_zoom_image_size">370</var>           <!-- New Product image size used for zooming -->

    <var name="product_image_white_borders">0</var>
</vars>
<vars module="Magento_Bundle">
    <var name="product_summary_image_size">58</var>
```

1MB